# jQuery isn't working after publish

Tags: jquery, asp.net, publish

When I test my web application locally, my jQuery works.  Specifically I am using *auto-complete*.. But, after I publish my app to my web server.. then the *auto-complete* does not work anymore..

I checked the folder where my app is being published to on the server, and checked the *jquery-ui* script to see if it contained *auto-complete* and it does.

Why is this happening? How do I get my jQuery to work on my server?

I am not receiving any errors in Developer Tools for this issue:

[image: Picture]

This picture was snipped while I was in the textbox where *auto-complete* should be happening

Here is my code to get my auto-complete to work:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('#Categories').autocomplete({
    source: function (request, response) {
        $.ajax({
            url: "/codeAC/AutoCompleteCategory",
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            data: { term: request.term },
            success: function (data) {
                response($.map(data, function (item) {
                    return { label: item.subcategory, value: item.subcategory };
                }))
            }
        })
    },
});
});
```

How I link my jQuery:

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/jquery-ui.js")
@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js")
@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/jquery-ui.js")
@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/jquery-ui.min.js")
@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/Scripts.js")
@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/moment-with-locales.js")
@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/moment-with-locales.min.js")
@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/moment.js")
@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/moment.min.js")
@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/bootstrap-datetimepicker.js")
@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js")
```

Comment: are you getting any error in console?

Comment: @DivyeshSavaliya when I publish I am not receiving any alert popup error..

Comment: Open the dev tools and look if you 're having any error

Comment: Your autocomplete data is static or is coming from some json file ?

Comment: Kinda bet that it is the way you "Link" to the jquery's in your html. Show is the Html.

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen edited question

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen I link all of my scripts in my `_Layout` view in MVC

Comment: First you need to fix your links, dont use the same script multiple times like moment.js and moment.min.js

Comment: Second i think its the "~" that makes the trouble for your server

Answer (score 0):

As I said in the Comments, your linking is wrong.

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/jquery-ui.js")
@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/jquery-ui.min.js")
@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/Scripts.js")
@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/moment-with-locales.min.js")
@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/moment.min.js")
@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js")
```

This is a more correct way, removing the duplicates.

Second I Think that the `~` in your links is the problem for your. Because `~` means Root and depending on the location of your website on the server it can be a problem.

Comment: I am also using jQuery for datepicker, and that works.. just not autocomplete

Comment: If your oploading it to a live site, can you provide me with the url, then i will check the reason why it dont work for you

Comment: Some people claim its teh jquery version that is the reason, because they say AutoCompleate need jquery 1.11.3 and you use 1.10.2. Try change that with <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>

Comment: sorry, that didn't work either.. but it does work while testing in local host

Comment: Sounds like it has something to do with where you upload it. Cant help much more information

Comment: found the issue. see my answer

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#Categories').autocomplete({
    source: function (request, response) {
        $.ajax({
            url: "/codeAC/AutoCompleteCategory",
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            data: { term: request.term },
            success: function (data) {
                response($.map(data, function (item) {
                    return { label: item.subcategory, value: item.subcategory };
                }))
            }
        })
    },
});
});
```

needed to be changed to:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#Categories').autocomplete({
    source: function (request, response) {
        $.ajax({
            url: "//*folder on server name*//codeAC/AutoCompleteCategory",
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            data: { term: request.term },
            success: function (data) {
                response($.map(data, function (item) {
                    return { label: item.subcategory, value: item.subcategory };
                }))
            }
        })
    },
});
});
```

Comment: This is the exact solution i was looking for!